# Export html to pdf in javascript

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I used [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to create a PDF from HTML

---

**Result :** it is generating the map without the path
Here is what I have:

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('pdf-canvas'), {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
          var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          var docDefinition = {
              content: [{
                  image: data,
                  width: 500,
              }]
          };
          pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
      }
  });
```

Then I used [canvg](https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg) and [fabric](http://fabricjs.com/)

---

**Result :** It is generating the path without the map
 
Here is what I have

```
1)fabric 

var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas( undefined, {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
} );
 var svgEl = document.body.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
 var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
 var svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svgEl);
 var path = fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgStr,function(objects, options) {      
   var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   canvas.add(obj).renderAll();      
   var data = canvas.toDataURL();       
   var docDefinition = {
       content: [{
           image: data,
           width: 500,
       }]
   };
   pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
 });

2)canvg

var svgImage = document.body.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var str = serializer.serializeToString(svgImage);   
var $canvas = $('<canvas/>');
$canvas.attr('width', '150px;')
$canvas.attr('height', '150px;')
$canvas.appendTo('body');
canvg($canvas.get(0), str);


html2canvas($canvas, {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a= canvas.toDataURL();
    var docDefinition = {
      content: [{
          image: a,
          width: 500,
      }]
  };
  pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("Score_Details.pdf");
  $canvas.remove(); //removes canvas from body
  }
});
```

Do I have to use another library or did I miss something using html2canvas, canvg and fabric ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a library using to export to PDF file, you can try it. [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Comment: I tried this library but this soultion not resolve my problem. the path is not generated